# Grub not coming up after ubuntu reinstall

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I reinstalled Ubuntu with an upgrade to 17.04, but now instead of grub it just blinks a similar color screen without showing grub itself and just boots to Ubuntu.

Grub fixing in Ubuntu didn't help, it seems like grub should be working but something is wrong with partitions..

It actually warned about something when installing Ubuntu - it said something about Bootloader not being the right partition.. it's a warning when installing Ubuntu, I don't remember it exactly though..

Comment: Is it possible that you have it booting from an SSD? If you have no delay on grub, and an SSD, it is near impossible to see the grub portion in this case. Check that you have a delay set in the grub.cfg.

Comment: I am booting from SSD.. how do I increase the grub delay? I have not configured it to have no delay

Comment: You can edit /etc/default/grub and look for GRUB_TIMEOUT= and then run update-grub

Comment: The timeout was there, but after I put the hidden timout plus increase timeout to 20sec - the problem is resolved (not sure which one actually worked)

Comment: Ok, go ahead and make an answer to your question and mark it as solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What worked was setting `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` to some seconds.

1. Edit Grub settings by editing `/etc/default/grub`, you can do so by:

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/default/grub
   ```
2. Set `GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT` to 10 seconds or whatever you prefer so the beginning of `grub` file now looks similar to this:

   ```
   GRUB_DEFAULT=0
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=10
   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
   GRUB_TIMEOUT=100
   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
   ```
3. Save the changes and reboot. If you used the above command in step (1) you can do so by pressing `Ctrl + X` then letter `Y` and then `Enter`.

Notice the `GRUB_TIMOUT=100` in my example .. that's to say that this setting doesn't work. I'll post an update if I find out why.. please do comment if you know why - I will pay the respects here, thanks.

Thanks @ben-Nabiy Derush for helping out to find the answer.

Comment: You can mark this as the solution as well.